# get out your books

Tags: phrasal-verbs

1) When we are in class, is it wrong to say "get out your books" to the students? Should it be "get your books out"? Is there a difference? Or should it be "take out your books / take your books out"? Are these separable phrasal verbs?

2) Is it incorrect to say "what page"? I know we have been taught "which page are we" but "what page are on" sounds also natural to me?

Comment: All those versions are acceptable.

Comment: thank you @kate